# Select rows in dataframe conditional on a switching boolean variable in another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

Let's say I have the following dataframe in R:

```
set.seed(23)

# Create sample data
time = 1:15
x = rnorm(n = 15) 
y = rnorm(n = 15)
boolean = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), 15, TRUE)
df <- data.frame(time, x, y, boolean)

# Output
> df
time           x            y boolean
1     1  0.19321233  0.308136896    TRUE
2     2 -0.43468211 -0.520178315    TRUE
3     3  0.91326710 -0.442313801   FALSE # select
4     4  1.79338809 -0.599312812    TRUE # select
5     5  0.99660511  1.294577829    TRUE
6     6  1.10749049  0.835391247    TRUE
7     7 -0.27808628 -0.566015100    TRUE
8     8  1.01920549  0.788419350   FALSE # select
9     9  0.04543718 -1.165929326    TRUE # select
10   10  1.57577959 -0.530820006   FALSE # select
11   11  0.21828845 -0.001058737   FALSE
12   12 -1.04653534 -0.512562365   FALSE
13   13 -0.28868865  1.242867513   FALSE
14   14  0.48155029 -0.660582851   FALSE
15   15 -1.21637643  0.166624215    TRUE # select
```

**Problem**

I would like to select all the rows, in which the boolean in the 4th column switches from `FALSE` to `TRUE` or vice versa (indicated in the dataframe above).

**Question**

How do I do this in R?

**Attempt**

I have found the `select()` and the `select_if()` functions in the `tidyverse package`, however, I am not able to select the values based on the previous value in the column.

Comment: Updated the data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rle` to create a counter which increments for every change in `boolean` value. We use `duplicated` and select only the first row for each counter. This will also select the first row but since it is not an actual change in `boolean` value, we remove that row (by using `[-1]`).

```
df[!duplicated(with(rle(df$boolean), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))), ][-1, ]

#   time           x            y boolean
#2     2 -0.43468211 -0.566015100    TRUE
#3     3  0.91326710  0.788419350   FALSE
#6     6  1.10749049 -0.001058737    TRUE
#8     8  1.01920549  1.242867513   FALSE
#9     9  0.04543718 -0.660582851    TRUE
#13   13 -0.28868865 -1.146665860   FALSE
#15   15 -1.21637643 -0.202111683    TRUE
```

The same logic can be applied using `data.table::rleid` which will make it a bit shorter

```
df[!duplicated(data.table::rleid(df$boolean)), ][-1, ]
```

---

In `dplyr`, we can create groups using `lag` and `cumsum` and select first row of every group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(boolean != lag(boolean, default = first(boolean)))) %>%
  slice(1L) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  slice(-1L) %>%
  select(-group)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(time = 1:15, x = c(0.19321233, -0.43468211, 0.9132671, 
1.79338809, 0.99660511, 1.10749049, -0.27808628, 1.01920549, 
0.04543718, 1.57577959, 0.21828845, -1.04653534, -0.28868865, 
0.48155029, -1.21637643), y = c(0.835391247, -0.5660151, 0.78841935, 
-1.165929326, -0.530820006, -0.001058737, -0.512562365, 1.242867513, 
-0.660582851, 0.166624215, -0.55320524, 0.098181415, -1.14666586, 
-1.249927257, -0.202111683), boolean = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14","15"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `base` solution::

```
df[c(FALSE, diff(df$boolean) != 0), ]

   time           x            y boolean
2     2 -0.43468211 -0.566015100    TRUE
3     3  0.91326710  0.788419350   FALSE
6     6  1.10749049 -0.001058737    TRUE
8     8  1.01920549  1.242867513   FALSE
9     9  0.04543718 -0.660582851    TRUE
13   13 -0.28868865 -1.146665860   FALSE
15   15 -1.21637643 -0.202111683    TRUE
```

This relies on taking the difference between `TRUE` and `FALSE`. If it's changing, the difference will be either -1 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

Using the helper function `shift()` from the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package (and the correct data provided by Ronak):

```
subset(df, boolean != shift(boolean, fill = boolean[1]))

   time           x            y boolean
2     2 -0.43468211 -0.566015100    TRUE
3     3  0.91326710  0.788419350   FALSE
6     6  1.10749049 -0.001058737    TRUE
8     8  1.01920549  1.242867513   FALSE
9     9  0.04543718 -0.660582851    TRUE
13   13 -0.28868865 -1.146665860   FALSE
15   15 -1.21637643 -0.202111683    TRUE
```